# CSS: Как нарисовать такой гексагон?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

Как нарисовать такой гексагон через CSS? Нарисовать нужно сейчас, а тему псевдоселекторов я так и не понял, если вы имеете, какие-то хорошие источники, где объясняют сложное по простому будет замечательно, чтобы навсегда закрыть этот вопрос.

Суть в том, что это будет кнопка, которая будет менять цвет при разных действиях по отношению к ней: `hover`, `focus`, `select` etc.

Вот собственно и сам компонент: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зачем мучаться и рисовать что-то в CSS, для чего он более чем полностью не предназначен. Все эти хаки с псевдоэлементами с отрисовкой каких-то сложных форм семантически не верны. Псевдоэлементы не для этого предназначены. Просто какой-то идиот впервые сделал это и остальные идиоты начали это копировать. Чтобы отрисовать такую кнопку легче всего, и что самое главное - правильнее, нужно использовать SVG, rоторый как раз для этого и предназначен. А менять цвета - вот это уже CSS!

Comment: @NoSkill с одной стороны - логично, с другой - я не понимаю: мне нужно передать в эти кнопки разные значения, как это делать, если это будет в SVG? И как придерживаться респонивного подхода, мне же нужно, чтобы кнопка при уменьшении или увеличении нормально отображалась на разных экранах

Comment: Можно же написать поверх SVG . При уменьшении кнопки - уменьшать шрифт. Можно сделать кнопку составной - левая часть, центр, правая часть. Центральная часть резиновая. SVG можно и в фон отправить. Возможностей как это сверстать - много.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написал для примера такой вариант. Согласен с @NoSkill - семантически это сложно, затратно по времени. К примеру, если в `r::beffore { margin-left: -18.5px;` поставить `19px` при некотором масштабе всё будет норм, но если изменить масштаб, норм не будет.

```js
document.querySelector('.box').onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector('.l').classList.toggle('l-active')
  document.querySelector('.r').classList.toggle('r-active')
}
```

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-25%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.r {
  width: 70px;
  height: 30px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)) drop-shadow(-1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)) drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)) drop-shadow(1px -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
  transition: 1s;
}

.r::before {
  content: '';
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 11px 10px 11px 0;
  border-color: transparent white transparent transparent;
  margin-left: -18.5px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.r::after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 11px 0 11px 10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent white;
  margin-left: 8.75px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.l {
  width: 110px;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -20px;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.3;
  align-self: center;
  transition: 1s;
}

.r:hover {
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 150, 0, 0.3)) drop-shadow(-1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 150, 0, 0.3)) drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0px rgba(0, 150, 0, 0.3)) drop-shadow(1px -1px 0px rgba(0, 150, 0, 0.3));
  background: green;
}

.r:hover {
  color: yellow;
}

.r:hover + .l {
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: -65px;
  background: green;
}

.r:hover::after {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent green;
}

.r:hover::before {
  border-color: transparent green transparent transparent;
}

.r-active {
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 150, 0, 0.3)) drop-shadow(-1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 150, 0, 0.3)) drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0px rgba(0, 150, 0, 0.3)) drop-shadow(1px -1px 0px rgba(0, 150, 0, 0.3));
  color: green;
}

.l-active {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <div class='r'>Content</div>
  <div class='l'></div>
</div>
```